# Anzograph - how to configure using different port for 5600

Tags: anzograph

I am trying to deploy Anzograph 2.0 (Linux tarball) and getting this error.
 
Could you please help out on debugging this?

```
> ./azg/bin/azg
Please read license at http://info.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/license
Confirm 'y' or 'n' that you agree to these license terms: y
Sysmgrd startup failed.
System error. Contact Cambridge Semantics Support. Reference: 0.0.0.0:5600: Could not connect to socket - Sysmgrd Failed to start
Starting AnzoGraph...
Error - Connect Failed: Connection Refused - StatusCode 14
```

In documentation, it lists port 5600 under Firewall Requirements but I checked with one of the admins and found out that port 5600 is occupied by default.  So, it is not possible to make a change to this port.

Is there a way to provide custom file option where we could provide ports of our choice during installation process? Or make a change in one of the configuration file where ports are specified?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use an alternate port by passing in the parameter -port in command string.  You will have to specify the port each time at command line.

To get you started in your 2.0 release
1) Do not use any of the other ports listed in the doc.  In my example it will be 5601
2) In your command, you will need to pass in parameter -port in your command,

First start up the daemon

$ ./azg/bin/azgmgrd -port 5601

Then start up the db with the same port as the daemon

$ ./azg/bin/azgctl -port 5601 -start

If all goes well,  you can then check on the process

$ ./azg/bin/azgctl -port 5601 -status

$ ./azg/bin/azgctl -port 5601 -version

If you want to stop the db, you would do the same and pass in the -port

$ ./azg/bin/azgctl -port 5601 -stop

$ ./azg/bin/azgctl -port 5601 -stopdaemon

Note, there was a change starting in 2.1 where one can update the settings.conf with the new port instead of issuing it manually.  There will be a new entry sysmgr_port to update with new port.